# Woocommerce add second checkout page for testing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I can customize checkout page overriding `/themes/../woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php`

But I want the copy of this page to test some features on it.
Can I create duplicate of checkout page for another URL path with the same content but different layout file?

Example:

- standard layout for users `/themes/../woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout.php`
- additional layout for admins `/themes/../woocommerce/checkout/custom-form-checkout.php`

And URLs will be:

- mysite.com/checkout/
- mysite.com/custom-checkout/

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is a pretty popular question for the woocommerce team - I found this thread from their staff that may be helpful to your question: [https://wordpress.org/support/topic/create-multiple-checkout-pages/#:~:text=You%20can%20create%20multiple%20Checkout,under%20WooCommerce%20%3E%20Settings%20%3E%20Advanced](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/create-multiple-checkout-pages/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20create%20multiple%20Checkout,under%20WooCommerce%20%3E%20Settings%20%3E%20Advanced).

Good luck!

Comment: They said that I need to do customization of the standard ckeckout page